# Show total value by month and difference in spotfire

Tags: visualization, spotfire, tibco, waterfall

Ive got the following plot in spotfire showing the total value per month and the difference of value from one month to the next
[image]

I need to show each month the total value of the month, not cumulative with past months, and also the difference, like shown below
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Spotfire. I would suggest you to have 2 different visualizations:

1. A Bar chart with the `Sum(Closing Value)`
2. A Waterfall chart with the `Difference`